# How to not show PHP error before i submited checkboxes

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm an getting the error

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for `foreach()`

in my code. But this is due to my checkboxes not being submitted in a form which is in another page. Can I somehow avoid showing the error or code something to check if `submit` is set before it throws out an error?

In my page2.php I have 10 checkboxes that display data. Once selected and submitted, it write the data using an `echo` and a `foreach()` loop on page1.php.
But the problem is that when I load page1.php before page2.php is submitted I obviously get an error is there a way around this?
Thanks.

my code on breakfast.php is:

```
error_reporting( E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE );

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    $foodchoice = $_POST['meal'];
}

?>
```

my code on homePage.php is :

```
if (isset($_POST['meal'])) 
{
   echo "yay!";
}

if (!isset($_POST['meal']))
{
    echo "nay!";
}
```

code that brings up the error on homePage.php:

```
<div id="equip" class="doc"> <section> <h3 id="title6"> Catering Selections </h3> </section> 
<center>

<?php  


foreach($_POST['meal'] as $checkbox){
    echo "</br> <li> ".$checkbox . '</li> ' ;
}  ?>


</center>
</div>
```

form data on breakfast.php

```
<form action="homePage.php" method="post">

 <input type='checkbox' value='The Share Collection' name = "meal[]" id='button3'>

<input type='checkbox' value='Assorted Biscuits' name = "meal[]" id='button3'>

<input type='checkbox' value='Fruit Skewers' name = "meal[]" id='button3'>

<input type='checkbox' value='Bread Project' name = "meal[]" id='button3'>
 <input type='checkbox' value='Cheese Project' name = "meal[]" id='button3'>

<input type="submit" id="button4" value="Submit Your Selection" name="submit">
```

On first load of homePage.php the result from the `isset` statement is nay and once submitted from breakfast.php it says yay!
    Please advise on a workaround.
Thanks

Comment: Can you please post the form html and the actual code where the error is. It sucks trying to guess

Comment: I know you are right will do. My answer is updated.

Comment: You are right. Its all there.

Comment: Your form's action is `action="homePage.php"` so which part of your code is homePage.php? and how are `page1.php` and `page2.php` referenced?

Comment: if you're trying to pass your POST arrays to multiple pages, use sessions. That's what this looks to me to be.

Comment: Updated to make it easier to understand.

Comment: @Fred-ii- so how could I use `SESSIONS` to solve this problem?

Comment: We don't need all the HTML code: all the `<dd>`, `<dl>`, `<br>`, `<img>`...are useless to show the problem you have. Keep only the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: And also please remove those unnecessary `<\br>` in both your code and here: `<br>` doesn't need a closing tag.

Comment: @Jocelyn cool thanks will do in the future. Good to know

Answer (score 0):

`$foodchoice = $_POST['meal[]'];` is the incorrect way to reference it.

just use

```
$foodchoice = $_POST['meal'];
```

then $foodchoice will be an array that you can loop through.

Comment: Thanks for your advice have change it to reflect that, but the error is still there on load.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to check which page the user came from.
Use it in an if statement to see if the user came from page 2.

Another option is adding a GET variable to the link that sends you from page 2 to page 1, on page 1 you could check if this variable is present to see if the result of the checkbox should be shown.